# DB migration with Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database

we are doing SQL Db migration with azure portal  now I need to automate this task (by using Az powershell).

steps we are following for manual approach

1. first we need to restore a tempDB from production db.
2. from the tempDB I need to export bacpac file for the bd
3. then import a this bacpac file into UAT database

can any one explain how I achieve this with Az-power shell?

steps I followed currently, I have installed Az powershell module in my local, trying to explore [Az.Sql  API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/?view=azps-3.2.0)

but I didn't find any API for DB export

Comment: When you say tempDB are you talking about the system database named TempDB or do you refer to a user database? You want restore the database where? Please explain more in details what you want to accomplish?

Comment: You've tagged Azure-DevOps. Is that where you want to do this from?

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://dbatools.io/commands/?  Looks like they have a command to cover all your needs.

Comment: How often did you need to automate execute the task? If you just for once, just do it manually. There isn't any API can do these steps auto in one command. These steps need to be execute one by one finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by "restore a tempDB from production db" you mean that you want to create a temporary working copy of the production db, then the solution is as follows:

1. Use [`New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy) to create a copy of the production db. *(you can delete the copy later after you're done using it with [`Remove-AzSqlDatabase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/Remove-AzSqlDatabase))*
2. Use [`New-AzSqlDatabaseExport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/New-AzSqlDatabaseExport) to export a .bacpac to a destination in an Azure Storage account.
3. Use [`New-AzSqlDatbaseImport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/New-AzSqlDatabaseImport) to import a .bacpac from a source in an Azure Storage account.

---

EDIT:

Instead, if by "restore a tempDB from production db" you mean a genuine restore, then the command [`Restore-AzSqlDatabase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/Restore-AzSqlDatabase) is what you should use.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?  I'd like the opportunity improve the answer if there's a problem with it.